# Printing ASCII letters, 10 is printed always at the end

Tags: c, ascii

I'm new to C and ASCII numbers, so I was using a code sample to print ASCII numbers

```
int main(){

    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
}
```

Output for "d" was

```
100
10
```

Whatever letter I tend to type, the result will be the ASCII code of said letter and 10 at the end as well. I'm not sure where this 10 is coming from.

Comment: It's coming from the Enter/Return key that you pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the code for the newline character that ended the input line.

if you want to stop at the end of the line and not include it, add another check.

```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
```